# Combining 2 Intervals

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, intervals, priority-queue

Given 2 Intervals with int start, int end and boolean status, Combine the 2 Intervals as shown below 
i1 and i2 are 2 `ArrayList<Intreval>` and res should contain the output of the combined intervals.

Example:

```
-INF --------- 6 ------- 10 --------- 30 --------- INF

       F           T             T           F

-INF --- 5 ------------------- 20 --------- 35 ---- INF

      T            T                  F         F
```

OUTPUT:

```
-INF ---5 ---- 6 -------- 10 -- 20 ---- 30 -- 35 --- INF

      F     F       T         T      F      F      F
```

The code creates i1 and i2 which are `ArrayList<Intervals>`. 
 `i1 has [[-INF,6,false],[6,10,true],[10,30,true],[30,INF,false]]` and 
 `i2 has [[-INF,5,true],[5,20,true],[20,35,false],[35,INF,false]]` and 
`res should contain [[-INF,5,false],[5,6,false],[6,10,true],[10,20,true],[20,30,false],[30,35,false],[35,INF,false]]`

Code:

```
Class Interval
{
  int start; 
  int end;
  boolean status;
  public Interval(int start, int end, boolean status)
  {
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
    this.status = status;
  }
}
  class MyCode {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Interval> i1 = new ArrayList<Interval>();
    i1.add(new Interval(Integer.MIN_VALUE, 6, false));
    i1.add(new Interval(6,10,true));
    i1.add(new Interval(10,30,true));
    i1.add(new Interval(30,Integer.MAX_VALUE,false));

    ArrayList<Interval> i2 = new ArrayList<Interval>();
    i2.add(new Interval(Integer.MIN_VALUE, 5, true));
    i2.add(new Interval(5,20,true));
    i2.add(new Interval(20,35,false));
    i2.add(new Interval(35,Integer.MAX_VALUE,false));

    int i=0, j=0;
    ArrayList<Interval> res = new ArrayList<Interval>();
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: How Do I find the intersection between two intervals and change the i and j values and add it to res? res should have the combined intervals i1 and i2 and the && of the intersection status.

Comment: What does the code do now, and what did you expect it to do instead?

Comment: The code creates i1 and i2 which are ArrayList<Intervals>.  i1 has [[-INF,6,false],[6,10,true],[10,30,true],[30,INF,false]] and i2 has [[-INF,5,true],[5,20,true],[20,35,false],[35,INF,false]] and res should contain [[-INF,5,false],[5,6,false],[6,10,true],[10,20,true],[20,30,false],[30,35,false],[35,INF,false]]

Comment: It's not clear why the expected result starts with `[-INF,5,false],[5,6,false]`.

Comment: -INF,5 is the first Interval among the 2 intervals (-INF,5 and -INF,6) and the boolean status would be i1.get(i).status && i2.get(j).status [here false&&true] which would result in [-INF,5,false]. Next, we would take [5,6] and status would be the && of the status of the two intervals which would give us [5,6,false] Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It's not for me to say. The question doesn't actually state the rules that are used to compute the output.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thank you for replying to the clarification questions asked in comments. Your added information is welcome. Please always [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55033363/edit) and add additional information there so we have everything in one place. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Intervals cover all the axis, so we can consider only left ends together with T/F field.

Ends are sorted, so apply merging procedure (like one from merge sorting).

```
 ia = 0
 ib = 0
 //Start the first output interval code

 while ia < ACount and B < BCount
    if A[ia].Position <= B[ib].Position
          ia++
          AActive  = True
    else if A[ia].Value >= B[ib].Value  //reuse == case for simplicity
                                        // and incrementing both indexes
          ib++
          AActive  = False

    State = A[ia].BooleanField && B[ib].BooleanField
    Pos = A[ia].Position if AActive else B[ib].Position 
    CloseOutputInterval(Pos)
    StartOutputInterval(Pos, State)

continue with the rest (A or B left)
```

Comment: It’s a good idea to offer pseudocode as here and let the asker do the concrete coding. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this works because you are either considering `A[ia].Position` or `B[ib].Position`. We also require the intersection of both of them in few cases. Which specific part this algorithm could assure that? @MBo

Comment: @user11223  Every new interval starts either from some `A[ia].Position` or from some `B[ib].Position`, or from shared point (here `B[ib].Position` is used). Boolean intersection is provided by `&&`  for current intervals.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Just for some clarification while I run through an example, When you say `if A[ia].Position <= B[ib].Position`, What do you exactly mean? Are you comparing the `A[ia].start with B[ib].start` or  `A[ia].end with B[ib].end`? or any other combination? @MBo

Comment: When all intervals are joined (without empty ranges), there is no need in end points, so I assume using only start points.

Comment: Yeah! Got it! Thanks